# How can I install the Spring Tool Suite in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, spring-tool-suite

How do I install STS on Ubuntu? I already downloaded the compressed STS tar.gz file from [spring.io](https://spring.io/).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Extract tar.gz file wherever you want

(for 64 Bit)

```
sudo tar -xvf spring-tool-suite-3.7.0.RELEASE-e4.5-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
```

(or for 32 Bit)

```
sudo tar -xvf spring-tool-suite-3.7.0.RELEASE-e4.5-linux-gtk.tar.gz
```

and you can start to use (/sts-bundle/sts-3.7.0.RELEASE/STS).

Comment: Note for 32 bit Ubuntu users - it looks like the last 32 bit tarball that's easily available on the STS site is for STS version 3.9.6. The 3.9.7 release download page ( https://spring.io/tools3/sts/all ) only has a 64 bit archive link.

Comment: not working in 2020. The answer needs to be updated.

Answer (score 60):

**Step 1**: Download the latest Spring Tool Suite for Linux from STS official website: https://spring.io/tools

**Step 2**: Extract into any folder which you prefer. My extracted Spring Tool Suite locations is /home/harishshan/springsource

**Step 3**: Create the Menu icon for quick access

```
sudo vim /usr/share/applications/STS.desktop
```

**Step 4**: Enter the following content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=SpringSource Tool Suite
Comment=SpringSource Tool Suite
Exec=~/springsource/sts-3.4.0-RELEASE/STS
Icon=~/springsource/sts-3.4.0-RELEASE/icon.xpm
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

**Step 5**: Now you can check from Quick Menu by typing "Spring"

> **Note:** Small additional update for Ubuntu 18.04 & STS 4+ use Absolute
> path instead of relative. Use
> `Exec=/home/harishshan/springsource/sts-3.4.0-RELEASE/STS Icon=/home/harishshan/springsource/sts-3.4.0-RELEASE/icon.xpm`
> dont'use `Exec=~somedir/harishshan/springsource/sts-3.4.0-RELEASE/STS Icon=~somedir/springsource/sts-3.4.0-RELEASE/icon.xpm`

Source : http://harishshan.blogspot.fr/2014/05/install-spring-tool-suite-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: +1; The STS should be about 379 MB and be called something like `spring-tool-suite-3.8.4.RELEASE-e4.6.3-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`

Comment: Another update - the executable is now called SpringToolSuite4 and not STS so the Exec path will have to be `/home/harishshan/springsource/sts-4.7.0.RELEASE/SpringToolSuite4`
This change would be applicable on STS 4+.

Comment: how do you make available for all users so you don't have to copy this large file into every user account?

Comment: Step 6 - right click, select 'Add to Favorites'  ;)

Answer (score 22):

1. Download the STS installer package (*.tar.gz) file to your downloads directory. At the time of this writing, that is...

   ```
   spring-tool-suite-3.9.5.RELEASE-e4.8.0-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
   ```
2. Expand the archive...

   ```
   tar -xzf spring-tool-suite-3.9.5.RELEASE-e4.8.0-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
   ```
3. Move the STS files to a good place for them to live. I like installing applications that will be possibly shared by multiple users, to the /opt/... directory.

   ```
   sudo mv sts-bundle /opt/sts
   ```
4. Stealing the rest of this from @Sangimed, because his answer was very good too.

   Create the Menu icon for quick access...

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/applications/STS.desktop
   ```

   Enter the following content

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=SpringSource Tool Suite
   Comment=SpringSource Tool Suite
   Exec=/opt/sts/sts-3.9.5.RELEASE/STS
   Icon=/opt/sts/sts-3.9.5.RELEASE/icon.xpm
   StartupNotify=true
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Keywords=Java,Eclipse,Spring,IDE,Development
   Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
   ```

Now you can just hit the ***"Windows"*** key on your keyboard and type "spring" to launch the application, like any other properly installed application on your Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

1. Extract the file
2. Go to **sts-bundle>sts-3.8.1.RELEASE** and click on **STS**
3. Start using

Answer (score 2):

You can use wget to download the file. To find the download link, go on Spring’s main website, right click on the download link for the package->

Select “Open Link in New Tab” ->

Copy and paste the new tab’s url into your wget command.

For example this command downloads the tar file:

```
wget “download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.9.0.RELEASE/dist/e4.7/spring-tool-suite-3.9.0.RELEASE-e4.7.0-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz”
```

Unzips the tar file:

```
sudo tar -xvf spring-tool-suite-3.9.0.RELEASE-e4.7.0-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple:

1. cd ~ && mkdir STS
2. cd ~/STS && tar -zxvf ~/Downloads/spring-*

Note: the last statement will look for all tar's with the naming 'spring-...'
before running this, make sure that in Downloads folder there's only one sts tar archive.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the STS download page at http://spring.io/tools/sts/all , choose linux and your architecture(x86-x64). Once the download is finished, go to the downloaded directory and extract the `.zip` file into a convenient directory of your choice. Open the extracted `sts-bundle` directory, right click `STS` then just click run.

Answer (score 0):

1.Download the tarball from the official website

2.Extract the tarball and run the STS file on Ubuntu

http://commandstech.com/how-to-install-stsspring-tool-suite-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-pictures/

4. Then create a sample project in STS

Answer (score 0):

If you already have Eclipse installed do next:

- Run Eclipse
- Help -> Eclipse Marketplace...
- Find -> Spring Tools 4
  Click Install button. Enjoy.